# Page scrolled up when opening bootstrap model

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, laravel-blade, bootstrap-5

when opening a model the page scroll to the top and stays at the top when model is closed

this is the html using blade engine

```
 <div class="row mt-0 name">           
 <a class="text-wrapper text-xs inviteeModel" id="inviteeModel"
          data-table="{{ $seatedTable->table->id }}"
          data-invitee="{{ $invitee['id'] }}"
          data-seats_taken="{{ $invitee['seats_taken'] }}"
          data-total_seats_taken="{{ $seatedTable->totalSeatsTaken }}"
          data-toggle="modal"                                               
          href="javascript:void(0)">
           {{ $invitee['name'] }}
           <span class="text-xs">
               ({{ $invitee['confirmed_invitees_count'] }})
           </span>
   </a>                                     
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                const tableInvitees = @json($seatedTable->invitees);
                console.log(tableInvitees);
                tableInvitees.forEach(function(invitee) {
                    $('.inviteeModel').click(function(e) {
                        const inviteeBtn = $(this);
                        const modal = $(`#table${inviteeBtn.data('table')}Modal`);
                        console.log(modal);
                        modal.find('input.invitee_id').val(inviteeBtn.data('invitee'));
                        modal.find('input.seats_taken').val(inviteeBtn.data('seats_taken'));
                        modal.find('input.temp_seats_taken').val(inviteeBtn.data('seats_taken'));
                        modal.find('input.total_seats_taken').val(inviteeBtn.data('total_seats_taken'));
                        modal.modal('show');
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

my body tag :

```
<body class="vertical-layout vertical-menu-modern  navbar-floating footer-static  " data-open="click"
    data-menu="vertical-menu-modern" data-col="">
</body>
```

Comment: Could perhaps be due to the link click default action, which you did not prevent in your click handler. (Using a `button` instead of `a` to trigger the modal, would be much preferable to begin with, IMHO. This _isn't_ a link.)

Comment: (And if your template code above is inside a loop, so that it outputs multiple times within the same page, then `id="inviteeModel"` certainly does not belong in there, that would get you duplicate IDs.)

Comment: I used Button with JavaScript listener to show the model still the same issue and i removed the id from the a tag

Answer (score 0):

To stop the bootstrap modal from scrolling, there is a property called backdrop. You need to set it as "static".

```
modal.modal({
   backdrop: 'static',
   keyboard: false
});
```

Try this out. Do let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I add it to JavaScript like this `modal.modal({
                            backdrop: 'static',
                            keyboard: false
                        });
                        modal.modal('show');` still not working